# How to sort a vector that has a type struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Hey guys so I was wondering how I could sort the elements in the vector in order. So far all I have done is declared `vector<struct i_like_words> da_list;`

and made:

```
struct i_like_words
{
    char real_char;
    int count;
};
```

but I'm having trouble coming up with the algroithm in sorting the elements.Much help would be appreciated

Comment: How do you want to sort? By real_char or by count?

Comment: How would you compare two of them? Start with that.

Comment: Write your own comparator function. Read the docs for more info and an example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: @BenjyKessler by real_char

Comment: The linked question from @huu is a solid duplicate source.

Comment: @AlexReynolds I'm getting errors it says incompatiable type